# Объединять повторяющиеся элементы от начала и записывать в соответствующие вложенности

Tags: javascript

```
let data = [
    [10, 101, 1001],
    [10, 101, 1002, 10003, 100004],
    [10, 102],
    [11, 111, 1111]
]
```

Есть массив элементов, где могут повторятся элементы,
нужно объединять такие элементы и записывать в соответствующие вложенности идущие следом элементы. Должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
[
    {
        id: 10,
        children: [
            {
                id: 101,
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 1001,
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        id: 1002,
                        children: [{
                            id: 10003,
                            children: [{
                                id: 100004,
                                children: []
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 102,
                children: []
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        children: [{
            id: 111,
            children: [{
                id: 1111,
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

Я перевернул  массив, что бы шли элементы по порядку от первых к последним, удалил дубликаты, но получается потерял связи...

```js
let data = [
    [10, 101, 1001],
    [10, 101, 1002, 10003, 100004],
    [10, 102],
    [11, 111, 1111]
]

let result = []
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        !result[j] ? result[j] = [] : null
        result[j].push(data[i][j])
    }
}

// получаю первые, вторые и тд эелементы, как бы переворачиваю массив,
// могу удалить все дубликаты ... new Set  но тогда я теряю связи
let unique = []
result.forEach( elem => {
  unique.push(...new Set(elem))
})
console.log(unique)
```

Даже в голову ничего не приходит, как тогда это сделать..

UPD

```
let data =
    [
        [{id: 10}, {id: 101}, {id: 1001}],
        [{id: 10}, {id: 101}, {id: 1002}, {id: 10001}],
        [{id: 10}, {id: 102}],
        [{id: 11}, {id: 103}, {id: 1003}],
        [{id: 11}, {id: 104}]
    ]
```

Comment: А что делать, если будет вот такой элемент массива `[101, 1003]`?

Comment: ну первый эелемент не совпадает ни с кем из существующих первых элементов, значит это будет отдельная ветка и не надо объединять.

Comment: Ага, хорошо. Тогда строите сначала плоский массив объектов с указанием id родителя. Потом этот массив превращаете в дерево - где-то на СО был алгоритм, или напишите свой, это не так трудно.

Comment: Уже пробовал так, потом большие сложности получаются с объединением одинаковых родителей, поэтому лучше сначала в плоском виде это как-то сделать. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222229/js-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно разбить на два шага

- Строите сначала плоский массив объектов с указанием id родителя.
- Потом этот массив превращаете в дерево

```js
let data = [
  [10, 101, 1001],
  [10, 101, 1002, 10003, 100004],
  [10, 102],
  [11, 111, 1111]
]

class TreeConverter {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  createNode(id, parentId) {
    return {
      id,
      parentId,
      children: []
    };
  }

  isExistInFlatNodes(flatNodes, node) {
    return !!flatNodes[node.id];
  }

  getFlatNodes() {
    const flatNodes = {};
    this.data.forEach(line => {
      line.forEach((el, i) => {
        const newNode = this.createNode(el, line[i - 1]);
        if (!this.isExistInFlatNodes(flatNodes, newNode)) {
          flatNodes[newNode.id] = newNode;
        }
      });
    });
    return flatNodes;
  }

  getTreeFromFlatNodes(flatNodes) {
    const tree = [];
    const nodes = Object.values(flatNodes);
    nodes.forEach(node => {
      if (node.parentId === undefined) {
        tree.push(node);
      } else {
        const parentNode = flatNodes[node.parentId];
        parentNode.children.push(node);
      }
    });
    return tree;
  }

  getTree() {
    const flatNodes = this.getFlatNodes();
    return this.getTreeFromFlatNodes(flatNodes);
  }
}
const converter = new TreeConverter(data);
console.log(converter.getTree())
```

Comment: ппц, как вы это сделали за пару минут?))) уже день даже алгоритм придумать не могу)))

Comment: @АндрейИванов Чем больше будете программировать, тем легче и быстрее будете это делать. Например, создание дерева, обход дерева - это довольно таки часто встречающиеся задачи.

Comment: Единственное, что мне пришлось придумывать нового - `this.createNode(el, line[i - 1])` - способ получения id родителя.

Comment: хм, я один момент никак не могу понять. Делаю всё тоже самое, но для реальной структуры, где будут не просто намбер элементы, а объекты сразу. обновил в вопросе. const parentNode = flatNodes[node.parentId] - это не понятно, типа обратиться по индексу, но как

Comment: @АндрейИванов все то же самое, с небольшим изменением `this.createNode(el.id, line[i - 1]?.id)`

Comment: я раскрыл объекты в createNode id: id.id, и это работает =)

Comment: @АндрейИванов да, так тоже можно.